# Extracting list elements from dictionary of lists in python using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5]}
```

and I need

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

using list comprehension. How do I do it?

Comment: Do you want the output in any particular order? (Python dictionaries are not intrinsically sorted.)

Comment: Order is not important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [val for lst in d.values() for val in lst]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But you may need to sort the dictionary first (because dicts are unordered) to guarantee the order:

```
>>> [val for key in sorted(d) for val in d[key]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: No. Sorting the list comp is better.

Comment: @MYGz That depends, I assumed he wanted to get all the values depending on the (sorted) order of the keys. Not sort all the values for all keys.

Comment: Thats right. Sort by key or sort by values. And 1 more possibility sort by both :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy and one liner solution using **list comprehension**:

```
>>> sorted([num for val in d.values() for num in val])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum(d.values(),[])` works but not performant because it applies `a = a + b` for each temp list.

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` instead:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.values())))
```

or sorted version:

```
print(sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.values())))
```

Comment: `chain.from_iterable` is probably better and faster than unpacking (`*d.values()`).

Comment: why do I always forget that?

Comment: Probably because it's more to type :-)

Comment: :) lesson learned. One should be alarmed when there's too many symbols in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If the order of elements is not important, then you cannot beat this:

```
sum(d.values(), [])
```

(Add `sorted()` if necessary.)